# How can salt "grow" up the wall of a vial with very salt water?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, phase-transition, physical-chemistry, crystals

In my kitchen I have a vial with very salt water, and some food coloring. It's been left to slowly dry out for a year or so. Recently, salt (presumably) started growing up the walls of the vial.

Does anyone have an explanation for what is happening here?
(I'm assuming this is physics, because I don't think it's alive or due to chemical reactions.)

[image]

Comment: A surface and/or capillary effect of liquid "climbing" and then evaporation at upper region with lower relative humidity, as vapour slowly escapes the vial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

surface tension tends to draw the water up the sides of the jar. evaporation then removes the water, leaving the salt behind as a porous layer on the jar surface. the capillary lift of water in the salt network is greater than the capillary draw on plain glass so water with salt in it continues to get pulled upwards through the salt, only to be evaporated away, leaving behind more salt higher up the walls, and so on.